# Building Collision Detection for Integer Arrays and Rectangles

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, gdi+

Collision Detection Between Integer Array and Rectangle C#

I am programming a remake of the old arcade game snake within a Windows Forms Application (.NET Framework) , I am currently using a GDI drawing surface to draw my snake, food(items to be collected) and my border around the game, the code for this is:

```
        private void gamearea_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics gfx = e.Graphics;
            Rectangle rectangle1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, gamearea.Width - 1, gamearea.Height - 1); // Draws a border
            gfx.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rectangle1);
            foreach (Point p in snakePointsQueue.ToList())
            {
                gfx.FillRectangle(Brushes.Purple, p.X * sizeX, p.Y * sizeY, sizeX, sizeY);
            }
            foreach (Point p in itemPoints.ToList())
            {
                gfx.FillRectangle(Brushes.Orange, p.X * sizeX, p.Y * sizeY, sizeX, sizeY);
            }
            if (gameover)
            {
                gfx.FillRectangle(Brushes.PaleVioletRed, failPos.X * sizeX, failPos.Y * sizeY, sizeX, sizeY);
                gfx.DrawString($"You Died! - SnakeLength : { snakeLength }", font, Brushes.Black, width / 2 - 20, height / 2);

            }
        }
```

I am attempting to get the rectangle, "rectangle1" to collide with an integer array that I have set up, "snakeArr":

```
int[,] snakeArr;
```

I am attempting to set up the program to check for this collision everytime my game runs the "tick" function.

```
int interval = 50 // speed of the snake in ms
timer = new Timer();
timer.Interval = interval;
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(tick);
timer.Enabled = true;

// tick function

private void tick(object sender, EventArgs e) // timer
        {

            direction = directionKeyDown;


            if (direction != "")
            {
                switch (direction)
                {
                    case "left":
                        {
                            if (x != 0) { x--; } else { x = width - 1; }
                            break;
                        }
                    case "right":
                        {
                            if (x != width - 1) { x++; } else { x = 0; }
                            break;
                        }
                    case "up":
                        {
                            if (y != 0) { y--; } else { y = height - 1; }
                            break;
                        }
                    case "down":
                        {
                            if (y != height - 1) { y++; } else { y = 0; }
                            break;
                        }
                    default: break;
                }
                // movement
                if (snakeArr[x, y] == 0)
                {
                    snakeArr[x, y] = 1;
                    // snake tail queue
                    snakePointsQueue.Enqueue(new Point(x, y));
                }
                // collision
                else { gameOver(); }
                if (foodArr[x, y] != 1 && snakeLength >= initialSnakeLength) // checking if the food has been eaten
                {
                    Point deq = snakePointsQueue.Dequeue();
                    snakeArr[deq.X, deq.Y] = 0;
                }
                else if (foodArr[x, y] != 1 && snakeLength < initialSnakeLength) // this is how the snake grows in size 
                {
                    snakeLength++;
                }
                else

                {
                    snakeLength++;
                    foodArr[x, y] = 0;
                    // new items to be collected
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (Point p in itemPoints.ToList())
                    {
                        if (p == new Point(x, y))
                        {
                        newItemPoint:
                            Point fPoint = new Point(random.Next(width - 1), random.Next(height - 1));
                            if (snakeArr[fPoint.X, fPoint.Y] > 0 || foodArr[fPoint.X, fPoint.Y] != 0)
                            {
                                goto newItemPoint;
                                ;
                            }
                            itemPoints[i] = fPoint;
                            foodArr[fPoint.X, fPoint.Y] = 1;
                            break;
                        }
                        i++;
                    }

                }
            }
            Refresh();
```

Below here is my full length code encase there is any confusion about how my game is working:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Snake_Progress
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        int x, y;
        int startX, startY;
        string direction = ""; // directional movement
        string directionKeyDown = "";
        int score = 0;
        int snakeLength;
        int initialSnakeLength = 1;
        int itemNumber = 25;
        int sizeX, sizeY;
        int width, height; // Width and height of the Array
        int[,] snakeArr; // array for the snake
        int[,] foodArr; // array for the food / item to be collected
        Rectangle rectangle1;
        List<Point> itemPoints = new List<Point>();
        Queue<Point> snakePointsQueue = new Queue<Point>();

        Point failPos = new Point();
        bool gameover = false;
        Font font = new Font("Calibiri", 18.0f);

        Random random;
        Timer timer;
        int interval = 50; // speed of the snake in ms


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            random = new Random();
            width = 40; height = 40;
            sizeX = gamearea.Width / width;
            sizeY = gamearea.Height / height;
            snakeArr = new int[width, height];
            foodArr = new int[width, height];
            startX = width / 2; startY = height / 2;
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = interval;
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(tick);
            x = startX; y = startY;
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            timer.Enabled = true;


        }

        // Four Directional Movement For When The Keys Are Held Down

        private void gamearea_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics gfx = e.Graphics;
            Rectangle rectangle1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, gamearea.Width - 1, gamearea.Height - 1); // Draws a border
            gfx.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rectangle1);
            foreach (Point p in snakePointsQueue.ToList())
            {
                gfx.FillRectangle(Brushes.Purple, p.X * sizeX, p.Y * sizeY, sizeX, sizeY);
            }
            foreach (Point p in itemPoints.ToList())
            {
                gfx.FillRectangle(Brushes.Orange, p.X * sizeX, p.Y * sizeY, sizeX, sizeY);
            }
            if (gameover)
            {
                gfx.FillRectangle(Brushes.PaleVioletRed, failPos.X * sizeX, failPos.Y * sizeY, sizeX, sizeY);
                gfx.DrawString($"You Died! - SnakeLength : { snakeLength }", font, Brushes.Black, width / 2 - 20, height / 2);

            }
        }


        private void Form1_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            Keys key = e.KeyCode;
            if (key == Keys.W && (direction != "down" || snakeLength == 0)) { directionKeyDown = "up"; }
            if (key == Keys.S && (direction != "up" || snakeLength == 0)) { directionKeyDown = "down"; }
            if (key == Keys.A && (direction != "right" || snakeLength == 0)) { directionKeyDown = "left"; }
            if (key == Keys.D && (direction != "left" || snakeLength == 0)) { directionKeyDown = "right"; }
            if (key == Keys.R) { newgame(); }

        }

        private void newgame() // function to start a new game
        {
            resetGame();
            snakeArr[x, y] = 1;
            snakePointsQueue.Enqueue(new Point(x, y));
            for (int i = 0; i < itemNumber; i++)
            {
                spawnNewItem:
                Point fPoint = new Point(random.Next(width), random.Next(height));
                if (snakeArr[fPoint.X, fPoint.Y] > 0 || foodArr[fPoint.X, fPoint.Y] != 0)
                {
                    goto spawnNewItem;
                }
                itemPoints.Add(fPoint);
                foodArr[fPoint.X, fPoint.Y] = 1;
            }
            timer.Enabled = true;
            gameover = false;
        }


        private void resetGame() // function to clear the previous games data (reset the game)
        {
            direction = "";
            Array.Clear(snakeArr, 0, snakeArr.Length);
            Array.Clear(foodArr, 0, foodArr.Length);
            itemPoints.Clear();
            snakePointsQueue.Clear();
            x = startX; y = startY;
            snakeLength = 0;

        }


        private void gameOver()
        {
            timer.Enabled = false;
            failPos = new Point(x, y);
            gameover = true;
            Refresh();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            newgame();
            Controls.Remove(button1);
        }

        private void button1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            newgame();
            Controls.Remove(button1);
        }

        private void tick(object sender, EventArgs e) // timer
        {

            direction = directionKeyDown;


            if (direction != "")
            {
                switch (direction)
                {
                    case "left":
                        {
                            if (x != 0) { x--; } else { x = width - 1; }
                            break;
                        }
                    case "right":
                        {
                            if (x != width - 1) { x++; } else { x = 0; }
                            break;
                        }
                    case "up":
                        {
                            if (y != 0) { y--; } else { y = height - 1; }
                            break;
                        }
                    case "down":
                        {
                            if (y != height - 1) { y++; } else { y = 0; }
                            break;
                        }
                    default: break;
                }
                // movement
                if (snakeArr[x, y] == 0)
                {
                    snakeArr[x, y] = 1;
                    // snake tail queue
                    snakePointsQueue.Enqueue(new Point(x, y));
                }
                // collision
                else { gameOver(); }
                if (foodArr[x, y] != 1 && snakeLength >= initialSnakeLength) // checking if the food has been eaten
                {
                    Point deq = snakePointsQueue.Dequeue();
                    snakeArr[deq.X, deq.Y] = 0;
                }
                else if (foodArr[x, y] != 1 && snakeLength < initialSnakeLength) // this is how the snake grows in size 
                {
                    snakeLength++;
                }
                else

                {
                    snakeLength++;
                    foodArr[x, y] = 0;
                    // new items to be collected
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (Point p in itemPoints.ToList())
                    {
                        if (p == new Point(x, y))
                        {
                        newItemPoint:
                            Point fPoint = new Point(random.Next(width - 1), random.Next(height - 1));
                            if (snakeArr[fPoint.X, fPoint.Y] > 0 || foodArr[fPoint.X, fPoint.Y] != 0)
                            {
                                goto newItemPoint;
                                ;
                            }
                            itemPoints[i] = fPoint;
                            foodArr[fPoint.X, fPoint.Y] = 1;
                            break;
                        }
                        i++;
                    }

                }
            }
            Refresh();
        }
        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                var parm = base.CreateParams;
                parm.ExStyle &= ~0x02000000;  //Turn off WS_CLIPCHILDREN 
                parm.ExStyle |= 0x02000000; //Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
                return parm;
            }

        }



        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Within the "tick" function I have attempted to use an if statement to check that the x, y values of snakeArr != gamearea.Width, gamearea.Height.

This was unsuccessful

I have also attempted to use an if statement within the tick function by first checking that the snakeArr is not empty, and if snakeArr [x, y] is equal to both gamearea.Width and gamearea.Height then the condition gameover is set to true.

```
            if (snakeArr[x, y] != 0)
            {
                if(snakeArr[x, y] == gamearea.Width && snakeArr[x, y] == gamearea.Height)
                {
                    gameover = true;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Tags in title: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: It is not really clear what the problem is. You have a new point, you have a bitmap where you can check if the point is free? If you need to handle borders, either just mark the border pixels as occupied, or use a *correct* border check for example: `((uint)x) < gamearea.Width`